# What files to exclude when setting up VS2013 project and perforce

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, perforce

A few friends and I are starting work on an independent project. We will be using VS2013 and perforce to share version-ed files. Are there any particular folders/files that should be excluded from the depot? I have heard several different reasons for several different files, but I cannot find any specific mentions.

The most common thing I've heard is to exclude the bin and obj folders, and the .csporj.user file. If anyone can confirm or give me additional information, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Without a language tag this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified the language is C#.

Comment: In addition to the files/folders you already mentioned, also exclude the .suo file. That's a user-specific solution-level file.

Comment: Instead of listing the files you should exclude, here's the list of files to include: *.sln, *.csproj, *.cs, plus all resource files you may have added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, bin and obj should be excluded, the reason being that they contain products of the compiler, which need not be shared.

As other people have already pointed out, user specific information should also be excluded from any kind of versioning. User specific settings need not be shared. Examples for user specific files in Visual Studio are the .suo and .user files.

If you plan on using any add-ins (such as Resharper) or nugget (which I highly recommend) do not forget to exclude any folders and files introduced by those - for example, the packages folder.

Those should be the most important ones.

For a pretty detailed list of files which you could possibly want to ignore please check out [this .gitignore file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore). But do keep in mind: Most of those ignores will not apply to your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks so much, the files/folder along with well explained reasons for each is great.